# Qt displayAlignment not aligning to the right

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qlistview, qstyleditemdelegate

I am writing an application using PyQt. I am using QListView with QStyledItemDelegate and I need to align some items on the left and some on the right. All of them are aligned on the left by default. However, I still don't get how to align them on the right. I fonud this question [How I can align values exported from database with query in PyQt5 table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448266/how-i-can-align-values-exported-from-database-with-query-in-pyqt5-table-view) which looks like something I need, but displayAlignment just doesn't seem to change anything. Here is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    QAbstractListModel,
    QMargins,
    Qt,
    QSize,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (
    QPainter,
    QFont,
    QFontMetrics,
)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QListView,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
)

BUBBLE_PADDING = QMargins(15, 5, 15, 5)
TEXT_PADDING = QMargins(25, 15, 25, 15)
FONT_SIZE = 14
FONT_STYLE = "Times"
font = 0

class MessageDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(MessageDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignRight

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        global font
        text = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        option.rect.setSize(self.sizeHint(option, index))
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignRight
        print(int(option.displayAlignment))
        bubblerect = option.rect.marginsRemoved(BUBBLE_PADDING)
        textrect = option.rect.marginsRemoved(TEXT_PADDING)
        painter.setPen(Qt.cyan)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.cyan)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(bubblerect, 10, 10)
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(textrect, Qt.TextWordWrap, text)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        global font
        text = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        metrics = QFontMetrics(font)
        rect = option.rect.marginsRemoved(TEXT_PADDING)
        rect = metrics.boundingRect(rect, Qt.TextWordWrap, text)
        rect = rect.marginsAdded(TEXT_PADDING)
        return rect.size()


class MessageModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.messages = []

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.messages[index.row()]

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.messages)

    def add_message(self, text):
        if text:
            self.messages.append((text))
            self.layoutChanged.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        global font
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        font = QFont(FONT_STYLE, FONT_SIZE)
        self.resize(int(QApplication.primaryScreen().size().width() * 0.3), int(QApplication.primaryScreen().size().height() * 0.5))
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.messages = QListView()
        self.messages.setItemDelegate(MessageDelegate())
        self.model = MessageModel()
        self.messages.setModel(self.model)
        self.model.add_message("Hello, world!")
        main_layout.addWidget(self.messages)
        self.w = QWidget()
        self.w.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[And here is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q3y4.png)
As you can see, the message is still aligned on the left despite the fact that the value printed in the paint function is 2 (`Qt.AlignRight`).
(I've assigned Qt.AlignRight 2 times, because the function `initStyleOption` is never called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the values of the style option only makes sense if they're used, for example when calling QStyle functions.

You're overriding `paint` by painting everything on your own, so any change in the style option is completely useless.
On the contrary, you should **not** change options (especially the `option.rect`) in any function except `initStyleOption`, but create a new instance of the option (or its objects) based on the one received as argument instead.

Since you want to align the rect to the right, you need to construct a new rectangle with its X coordinate based on the option rect's right *minus* the desired width.

```
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        text = index.model().data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
        size = self.sizeHint(option, index)
        rect = QRect(
            option.rect.right() - size.width(), option.rect.y(), 
            size.width(), size.height())
        bubblerect = rect.marginsRemoved(BUBBLE_PADDING)
        textrect = rect.marginsRemoved(TEXT_PADDING)
        painter.setPen(Qt.cyan)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.cyan)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(bubblerect, 10, 10)
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.drawText(textrect, Qt.TextWordWrap, text)
```

<sup>Globals should always be avoided whenever it's possible (don't use them if you don't know how to use them, aka: if you know how to use them, you won't use them). If you want to set a font for the delegate, then add an argument for its `__init__` with the preferred font, and set it as instance attribute.</sup>